# Why is the reason desktop app V3 connection failed after entering all details?

Tags: microsoft-translator

With document translator desktop app, getting an error "*test failed: Resource name incorrect or not a paid subscription*". I'm sure all information is correct since all details in Azure were configured and provided from my local azure cloud administrator. Any guidance will be very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The older "Document Translator" app only works with a resource in the "global" region. Please upgrade to the newer "Document Translation" app.

https://github.com/MicrosoftTranslator/DocumentTranslation/releases

This version requires an Azure Translator resource, any region, and an Azure Storage resource. Be sure to get both from your company's Azure administrator. For the Translator resource you need the name and the key, for the Storage resource you need the connection string.